# How to retrieve a system file of Android?

Tags: wifi-tethering, samsung-galaxy-ace

I ve deleted the file "fw_bcm4329.bin" from the root of the SD card,
right now I cannot connect by my pc with the tethering of android.

Anyone knows how to retrieve this file?

I have a

Samsung Galaxy Ace S5830
with Android 2.2.1 Froyo

thank You

max

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean here. Are you saying you deleted this file from your SD card, and that it was a copy of a file from your system? Are you asking how to recover deleted files? It looks like a firmware file for your wifi chip, so if you only deleted the copy on your SD card then it's presumably still around somewhere else.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Data Recovery - How to Restore Deleted / Formatted Files on HD Micro SD Card](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7069/data-recovery-how-to-restore-deleted-formatted-files-on-hd-micro-sd-card)

Comment: I'm going to assume OP didn't mean the root of the SD card, and instead meant the root of the filesystem. :)

Answer (score 1):

[This XDA post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=697168) provides a Multiupload link, where you can download that file.

Answer (score -2):

I have used the ASTRO File Manager. You should be able to use this free Android Market app to locate and manage all the root files. If you deleted this firmware binary file in the SD card, it probably is gone. I have not heard of any undelete app for Android.