# Have I erased my songs? Samsung galaxy S2

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, data-recovery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Data Recovery - How to Restore Deleted / Formatted Files on HD Micro SD Card](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7069/data-recovery-how-to-restore-deleted-formatted-files-on-hd-micro-sd-card)

I removed everything by entering code in phone field. I deleted my all apps. What about my photos and songs? Have I erased it too?

Comment: What code? Your photos and songs are probably still there. Have you connected your phone to a PC via USB and looked?

Comment: @AlEverett: I don't actually remember. Storage shows that I have 14gb free space out of ~14.6gb. So everything's gone...? :( I don't have USB too...

Comment: Then you need to install some sort of file manager like ASTRO and see if your data's gone. It sounds like it might be. You weren't backing up to the cloud?

Comment: @AlEverett: I will have apps back as I have google account with it (when I will have wifi). Omg, I can't believe how stupid I am...

Comment: If you don't know what code it was I think it's impossible to tell you exactly what happened.  As for recovering your data I think the linked duplicate should help.

Answer (score 0):

If your lucky, you might find some files back with [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva). Plug your phone in your PC. Start Recuva. Select the drive representing your phone and execute the scan. It will show anything it finds. Though I doubt it will find anything back, phones usually use Flash memory, and once you delete something on a Flash drive, it's completely gone.