# How to recover data from a damaged SD card?

Tags: external-sd, data-recovery

I have an HTC Inspire.  I have had my 8 GB SD Card for three years...needless to say, it has like 5000 pictures and hundreds of videos on it.  It has a lot of music on it too, but I'm not worried about that.  I just want my pictures back more than anything.  I got a message on my phone that told me I should safely unmount my SD card before removing it.  Since I haven't taken it out for months, I didn't think anything of it.  A few hours later, it said "SD Card damaged.  You may have to reformat it."  When I clicked on that, it said "Are you sure you want to format the Sd card?  All data on your card will be lost."

I have tried plugging it into the computer, but there's not an option to view files.  I tried putting it in my dad's phone, and his phone didn't even recognize that it was even in there.  If anyone has ANY ideas, whatsoever, it would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!!

Comment: I assume you canceled the format.  Did you try plugging the card (without the phone) in to a PC (via an adapter or what have you)?

Comment: Do you have ClockWorkMod installed?

Comment: To try to get your pictures back, have a look at the options on this older questions: [Data Recovery - How to Restore Deleted / Formatted Files on HD Micro SD Card](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7069/)

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem with my SD card and Samsung Galaxy S a while ago. The solution was to plug the card into a card reader and run `chkdsk x: /F /V` to repair the file system.

If this doesn't work, you'd have to use some file recovery software to fish out the files from a broken file system. There are many different applications for this, you can find some by googling for "file recovery free", or try [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec).

Comment: How successful in recovering files is PhotoRec? This same situation being the use case.

Comment: I haven't used it on SD cards, but it was very handy when my external hard drive screwed up it's master file table, recovered every single file.

Comment: If you have a damaged SD card that neither programs nor companies\stores can recover the data from, I shipped mine to Germany to a place called **RecoverFab**: http://recoverfab.com/ 
1-2 days after they received it, 100% of photos and videos recovered. SUCCESS! I tried Transcend in Taiwan first, the makers of my SD card could not recover data off of it, RecoverFab did.

I'm sold. [answering here b/c it won't let me answer normally, protected?]

Answer (score 2):

Use [Card Data Recovery](http://www.card-data-recovery.com). It can help you recover data from SD card.

Comment: Crashes after a while under Windows 7 x64. Installs `TenorshareNCDRService` crapware service. Does not remove it on uninstall, needs to uninstall it separately.

Answer (score 0):

If you have ClockWorkMod flashed you can try mounting the SD card to USB when you have booted up in the recovery mode.

Answer (score 0):

The most popular free program for data recovery is **[Recuva](https://www.piriform.com/recuva)**. For advanced recovery, you need to upgraded to Pro version. Another available options is **Dr.Fone for Android**. It has a default function to recover deleted files form SD card. [Here](http://www.androidphonesoft.com/resources/recover-deleted-files-from-android-sd-card.html) is the tutorial.

P.S. For important data, it is highly recommended to backup in different devices or with cloud service.