# How can I recover corrupt files from my SD Card on my PC?

Tags: data-recovery, external-sd

My LG Marquee started boot looping four days ago and because of this, I have not been able to get into my files (photos, videos, apps, etc.) and back them up. I have not backed up *any* of my files, unfortunately. A user on here gave me the idea to salvage my media content via copying my SD Card's contents to my PC, then copying these files to a new card and placing the new card in my phone - thus recovering my important files.

My phone is **not** rooted.

I bought a better SD Card and an SD Card reader and just tried copying my content to my PC. All photos and videos are showing up as *Invalid Image* :(

My Questions:

- **Does this "Invalid Image" prompt mean that the files are corrupt...forever?**
- **Could this be caused by the software I am viewing the files in, and if I view them in a different software, will they show up fine?**
- **Is there any way (via a photo recovery software) that I can recover these corrupt files? If so, what software(s) do you personally recommend?**

Thank you for any and all questions answered.

I really appreciate it, I am at my wit's end with this problem and I had thousands of photos that were *extremely* important to me - losing them would honestly be devestating.

**Update**: I ejected the reader and inserted it again, and instead of being able to at least view the "Invalid" images, now my computer is prompting me to format what it is calling the *Removable Disk (E:)*

Should I go ahead and format my card on my PC? I'm so lost :(

Comment: Have you just unplugged it, or did you check the "safely remove" dialog of your PC's OS first? If you skipped that step, you might have added further damage. A suggestion is also to follow the [data-recovery + sdcard](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-recovery+sd-card) tag link -- this kind of question is not asked here for the first time, so you already will find useful recovery programs mentioned and even described. See e.g. [How to recover data from a damaged SD card?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/21141/16575)

Comment: I now realize that was my mistake. I did not "safely remove" the hardware. Yikes! Very bad mistake. Anyway, I was able to recover the files from PhotoRec. **All** of my files were recovered, though some of my MP3's were quite butchered afterward. That's OK though, I just really wanted my photos back and I got them. Thank you **SO** much for your help! I had an emotional attachment to many of those photos, and you and PhotoRec (as well as other users on here) have helped me to get them back when I thought there was no way :) Thank you very much!

Comment: Yepp, PhotoRec is a good choice. As your problem luckily is solved, I hope you don't mind if I initiate to close this question as a duplicate to the corresponding one ;) Glad I was able to help!