# my sd card suddenly crashed

Tags: external-sd, data-recovery

In a morning time i was seeing pictures in my phone.
After 2 hour i saw my phone ( Samsung galaxy y ) it was
show memory card unavailable.
I did reinsert memory card many time in my phone and also in computer. But it can not find that..
i have captured many pictures at vocation time it was very important for me.
Please help me  can i recover my pictures ? please please help me. what i do ?

Comment: That sounds like your card is just dying (or already has died). If I read your question correctly, you can mount and read the card just fine – but some files are disappeared? If so: are all newer files gone? // It could also be you've (accidentally) deleted those files. In that case, please check our [data-recovery tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/data-recovery/info) for first aid, and especially check [How to Restore Deleted / Formatted Files on HD Micro SD Card](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/7069/16575).

Comment: Also see: [How to recover data from a damaged SD card?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/21141/16575)

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning it, if it's broken not much you can do except trying again. If it's really really important you can send it to experts maybe they can recover something !

Comment: I doubt that helps. If it would be that, the entire card would be unreadable; there's nothing you can "clean" to show a specific file – either contacts are really dirty (then the card doesn't mount), or the card mounts fine (then there's nothing to clean).

Comment: So it's recognized ! Try recueva a nice program to recover files

Answer (score 0):

Micro SD cards have a nasty habit of crashing at the most annoying times. There is not much you can do if your sd card has truly died other then buy a new one and hope your files were backed up. Sometimes you can recover a card if it's simply corrupt but if your cards controller goes pumpkin witch they do tend to do a lot these days your sol.