# Is there a way to recover deleted photos?

Tags: data-recovery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I recover a deleted file on Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15869/how-can-i-recover-a-deleted-file-on-android)
>   [Data Recovery - How to Restore Deleted / Formatted Files on HD Micro SD Card](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7069/data-recovery-how-to-restore-deleted-formatted-files-on-hd-micro-sd-card)

Is there a way to recover deleted photos from my device? I deleted some pictures but now I want to restore them. I tried several file recovery applications, but they only gave me empty image files.

Comment: Have you looked at [How can I recover a deleted file on Android?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/15869)

Comment: If none of the tools work then your images have probably been overwritten and are now unrecoverable, unfortunately.