# i have lost my images by deleting them but now i want them back

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, data-recovery

last day my pictures were deleted by mistake i have tried to acquire them back by simply logging into samsung account . How can i get my pictures back by using my samsung account ?

Comment: This is a quite frequent question here. Please see: [How can I recover a deleted file on Android?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/15869/16575) / [Data Recovery - How to Restore Deleted / Formatted Files on HD Micro SD Card](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/7069/16575) / [Restore deleted photos](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/36521/16575) / our [data-recovery tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/data-recovery/info).

Comment: What has your Samsung account got to do with it? Do you have your phone set to back up photos to Samsung servers?

Answer (score 0):

I've done this before and this is how I got them back:

First things first:  STOP using your phone as much as possible, specifically you don't want to do anything that may overwrite the area where your pictures are.  When you "delete" something, the memory where it is stored is marked as free to be overwritten by other data.  Until this happens you can recover them because they are still there, just waiting to be overwritten by other data.

Here is what I did:

1. I did a search and found some free file recovery software for my laptop.  I'm not sure what program I used, but there are plenty that can be found for free if you look.  Maybe someone else has some advice on this part?  In fact, many of these programs can be run off a USB stick and may not even need to be installed.  Just search around.
2. Using your phones USB cable, plug it in to your/a PC where your deleted file recovery software is installed. Mount the SD card, assuming that is where your photos were stored.  If not then just make sure you have access to your phones internal storage from your PC.
3. Point your file recovery software to your phone/sd card and start it running.  It should find all your pics, and probably a bunch of other stuff.

This type of software usually allows you to pick the location you want it to check as well as a time frame so you can search files deleted in the last 24 hours, last week, or last month etc.  Depending on the software you download there could be other options such as file types to look for.

If you are a Mac user I'm fairly certain this would work the same way, although I've never tried it with my Mac.

Good Luck!  This saved my kids Christmas pictures and about 1200 other ones last year when I accidentally deleted them, so I hope you have a similar experience.