# HTC One Mini data recovery after root

Tags: data-recovery, htc-one-mini

Last night I wiped and rooted my HTC One Mini and lost a few photos. Is there any way to get them back?

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts, Aaron! That's one of our more frequent questions, so we've set up some "first-aid-info" in the [data-recovery tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/data-recovery/info) you might wish to check (always a good idea to check tag-wikis, as that's not the only one ;) Especially take a look at [How can I recover a deleted file on Android?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/15869/16575) and [Data Recovery - How to Restore Deleted / Formatted Files on HD Micro SD Card](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/7069/16575).

Comment: @Izzy Thanks! "File carving [..] Recover accidentally formatted devices" - seems like this is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Izzy Might want to put that in an answer as it sounds like you hit the nail on the head. ;)

Comment: As requested: Answer posted :) Glad I was able to point into the right direction (or even "hitting the nail on the head" :) Good luck on restore!

Answer (score 0):

That's one of our more frequent questions, so we've set up some "first-aid-info" in the [data-recovery tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/data-recovery/info)<sup>1</sup>. Especially take a look at

- [How can I recover a deleted file on Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/15869/16575)
- [Data Recovery - How to Restore Deleted / Formatted Files on HD Micro SD Card](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/7069/16575)

Also, the links to details on "File Carving" and specific recovery tools might prove helpful.

---

<sup>**1:** It's always a good idea to check our tag-wikis, as they often contain such "first aid" or at least useful information/links. You can find them either hovering your mouse over a tag and click the "info" link inside the opening box – or simply click the tag, and select the left-most tab on the new page.</sup>