# If I deleted photo from gallery made backup before flashing, will I get that photo in the backup?

Tags: backup, samsung, formatting, samsung-galaxy-grand

My phone is Samsung Galaxy Grand. If I delete a photo from the gallery and make a backup before flashing, will I get that photo in the backup?

Answer (score 3):

That very much depends on the type of backup you are talking about. As the photo was deleted, none of the usual backup approaches would cover it: a backup only takes what is there, not was was deleted.

How to recover that photo (if possible) depends not at last on where it was stored:

- external SDCard: safely remove it from the device, and use a card reader to check for deleted files with your computer and an application like *[PhotoRec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhotoRec)*
- internal SDCard: not that easy. You have to clone that partition (a [nandroid](/questions/tagged/nandroid) backup usually does this), transfer it to your computer, and analyse it with an application like *[TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)* or *[Scalpel](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Scalpel)*

Details and further hints can be found e.g. in our [data-recovery tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/data-recovery/info). See e.g.:

- [How can I recover a deleted file on Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/15869/16575)
- [How to Restore Deleted / Formatted Files on HD Micro SD Card](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/7069/16575)

Answer (score 1):

Usually, flashing of the ROMs only affects files that are stored on your /system partition. Photos are stored on a SD card, and won't be deleted when you flash a ROM.

As for deleted photo, once it's deleted it can't be restored by normal methods. You could try [restoring deleted files](http://www.androidpit.com/how-to-recover-lost-data) (there are many articles on the Internet regarding that, try searching for "restore deleted photos on android")