# Accidentally formatted SD Card, can all files be recovered?

Tags: sd-card, data-recovery, partitions, formatting

The phone is rooted and the SD Card has been partitioned before. I was trying to adjust the partition size using Apps2SD but it ended up formatting it. Is there any way I can recover the lost files? The files are mostly apps/games.

EDIT: Just to clarify, can the games/apps itself be recovered? Or at least their data? I need the game data as some of my games are single-player and it'll really suck to start all over again.

Comment: Well, you can easily download the apps and games again. For unique files you want to recover (photos, videos etc), you can use tools on PC like Recuva or other file recovery applications (there are some for Android but there are more hit and miss and often miss).

Comment: @GiantTree It should be mentioned that Recuva fails for certain if the external SD is formatted in either ext4 or f2fs.

Comment: For a starter, you could check with our nice [data-recovery tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/data-recovery/info) – which would e.g. bring you to [How to Restore Deleted / Formatted Files on HD Micro SD Card](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/7069/16575). The tag has many more :)

Comment: @GiantTree Well, yeah, I could re-download those apps again, but my problem is the data for those games. Some of my games are only single-player so the data doesn't save online, which means I'll have to start from scratch again :( Is there any way to recover game data?

Comment: App data is (usually) _not_ saved on the SD card. You'd only lose their *.obb data files.

Comment: @Andy Yan Hmm, but all of my games are linked/moved to the EXT2 partition of the SD Card (With the help of Apps2SD of course), so the game data has also got be there too, right?

Comment: I'm at a bit of loss on that one, since I never used such "move to SD" features. Check out `/data/data/*package name of your app*`, there should be a complete folder structure there storing your app data (usually in databases, files or shared_prefs), if you can't see anything meaningful in there then it's indeed linked and lost.

Comment: Please, connect the card to a computer, run TestDisk to scan it and then report the results here.